# How can I combine two Function0 val's into one Function0

Tags: scala, scalaz

I imagine something like this:

```
def combine[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): (M[A], M[B]) => M[C]
```

while `M` would be `Function0`. Is this possible in scalaz?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question. As it is written, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @mepcotterell I disagree. He gave the typesignature, which should be enough.

Comment: Actually there is only one extensionally equivalent implementation of a function with this signature. As for implementation, there are many ways to implement it with scalaz, because this pattern is so incredibly common in every-day programming. It is often described as "lift-2." Notice you can rearrange the signature to be: (A => B => C) => (M[A] => M[B] => M[C]). It is as if you are "lifting" the function (arity-2) into environment M.

Comment: As scala is not a pure language, I would like the the functions I pass into `combine` to be able to perform side-effects, like reading a var.

Answer (score 1):

```
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._

def combine[A, B, C, M: Applicative](f: (A, B) => C) = 
   (ma: M[A], mb: M[B]) => (ma |@| mb)(f)
```

Comment: This definition works well as long as the functions I pass into are pure since the first function gets only executed once. Is this behavior intended by scalaz?

Answer (score 0):

In standard scala it is not that hard, simply stick to your signature:

```
def combine[A,B,C]( f: (A,B) => C ) 
  = ( fA:(()=>A), fB:(()=>B) ) => f( fA(), fB() )
```

Here is a small example:

```
scala> val isProdPositive = combine( (i:Int,d:Double) => i*d > 0.0 )
  isProdPositive: (() => Int, () => Double) => Boolean = <function2>

scala> val f1 = () => 2
  f1: () => Int = <function0>

scala> val f2 = () => -1.5
  f2: () => Double = <function0>

scala> isProdPositive(f1,f2)
  res1: Boolean = false
```